# How can I fade a group of objects grouped to one empty in the same time?

Tags: animation

The parts of the group have different materials applied to them.
The parts of the groups are not in the same collection.
I want to fade the whole group of assembly to transparency at the same time in the animation.

Thanks!

Comment: Fade to what? Transparency?

Comment: Yes, make them gradually transparent in animation. I can fade out one material using Mix Shader, but I don't know how to fade several materials/objects together.

Comment: The most flexible way to this would probably be in the compositor. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one common node group in different materials:

[image]

Inside the group, you can see mix node. It blends material with transparent

[image]